# Text-to-speech program on Windows saying "ASCII"

Tags: windows-7, accessibility, ascii, text-to-speech

I am using Windows native text-to-speech program to read web pages and pdf files.
Whenever the reader encounters a special character (or a blank space of some sort), it says "ASCII". Is there a way to make the reader skip such characters or not say "ASCII" at all?

Comment: Native text-to-speech program? Is it Narrator?

Comment: It's the predecessor of Narrator. `In Windows Vista and Windows 7, Narrator has been updated to use SAPI 5.3 and the Microsoft Anna voice for English.` [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Narrator)

Comment: A predecessor of Narrator? SAPI refers to the voice engine. The *program* called Microsoft Narrator has been included with Windows since 2000, with various versions. Windows 7's version uses SAPI 5.3, but the program is still called Narrator. Microsoft Office, for example, also uses SAPI in its built in text-to-speech functions. My question to you is, *what is the name of the program you are using for text-to-speech?* SAPI appears to store some settings in `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Speech` and `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Speech`.

Comment: Oh I see. My misunderstanding. I am using Adobe Acrobat Reader for pdf's and Announcify Chrome Extension for webpages. I have glanced over the registry, but I am not quiet sure where this feature (or bug) can be modified.

Comment: Could you provide an example file or sentence of some sort? Testing Adobe Reader X's `Read Out Loud` using Microsoft Anna on Windows 7 on a document with random alt code characters (`Testing testing 123 ˜⾅  㤾× Testing`) just reads "testing testing one hundred twenty three tilde <pause> testing"... in other words, it skips the unpronounceable characters. Check `Edit` > `Preferences` > `Reading`, which voice is selected? Also check the voice selected (and voices available) in `Change text to speech settings`, available from Start Menu search.

Comment: Could you please try reading this [page](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2009sp/lectures/lec05.html) with [announcify](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mmiolkcfamcbpoandjpnefiegkcpeoan) chrome plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not provided a sample PDF document, so I could not test that.

---

Testing your provided [page](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2009sp/lectures/lec05.html) with Chome's Announcify plugin:

It doesn't say `ASCII` (not `ay ess see eye eye` nor `ass-kee`) for me. On some spaces, it does say `dot and n b s p <pause>`. Looking at the source code for the page, it is evident that Announcify is not converting HTML elements before sending them to the speech engine. The `dot` is the full stop (period). `&nbsp;` is an HTML element, non-breaking space, which should have been converted to a space before reading. That's a bug in Announcify which should be reported to its developers. Special characters could be encoded similarly; an ampersand would be `&amp;`. The `;` becomes a pause, as a semicolon is supposed to be read in English.

Microsoft's text to speech engine is designed for literary text. More technical texts, especially in programming where punctuation should be read out, could cause problems. For example, the speech engine pauses when reading the colon (`:`) and comma (`,`), and completely ignores quotes, as should happen if it were reading an English literary passage. There's not much you can do about that.

Comment: For me, I found that the previously described issue occurs when I have double space. It may have to do with the Unicode setting on my OS. I am currently learning javascript to remove double space into single space, but thank you for describing the inherent nature of the problem.

Comment: It's not a double space, more a special space. The thing is, after each `&nbsp;` is a normal space, so it looks like a double space. In that particular document, you can just strip out the `&nbsp;`s... but for a more compatible solution, replacing with normal spaces should work.

Comment: The real problem here is Announcify is throwing the HTML source at the text-to-speech engine, rather than the rendered HTML as its supposed to.

Comment: I looked through userscript.org to see if nbsp can be removed. None of the scripts worked, do you happen to know the solution?